# Image rendering error in nextjs production

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

in Nextjs13.5.6 i am dynamically uploading images and try to render them in another page. but it returning error as follows

```
The requested resource isn't a valid image for /uploads/img-an-imgase.png received text/html; charset=utf-8
```

but when i run the in development it's working flawlessly.
when i try to rebuild the app after the upload it also working.

In porduction enviroment only current uploaded images are unable to render. previosly uploaded images (before build) are okay.

I don't have any clue what is go on and how to solve it

```
<Image
   width={360}
   height={360}
   src={product.imageUrl}
   alt="Product Image"
   className="object-cover mx-auto"
/>
```

Note: url is okay

Comment: somebody told this "You have to rebuild [ npm run build ] the project after adding new assets, then commit the changes." this is working fine, but can't rebuild everytime when user uploads a picture

Comment: you should not use the next Image.. ***<img src='...' />*** use this , it never gives an error in production

Comment: I will check it out and then I will inform you. but with respect to your answer I will loose image optimisation in my app.

Comment: It's absolutely right

Comment: are there any other way to do the same thing without losing the image optimisation?

Comment: optimize by quality and code

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain little bit?

Comment: ***https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas*** it can optimise images on the Server side

Comment: I tried bro but not working. only works after rebuild

Comment: Every time rebuild for static data, not for dynamic .. You have to store data in the database when user uploads a picture